# Error: Type 'ui.TextHeightBehavior' not found in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, android-app-bundle, flutter-channel, flutter-build

I got a problem when I flutter build appbundle in terminal command

Compiler message:

```
    ../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/basic.dart:5149:9: Error: Type 'ui.TextHeightBehavior' not found.
      final ui.TextHeightBehavior textHeightBehavior;                       
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                           
    ../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/text.dart:149:9: Error: Type 'ui.TextHeightBehavior' not found.
      final ui.TextHeightBehavior textHeightBehavior;                       
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                           
    ../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/text.dart:432:9: Error: Type 'ui.TextHeightBehavior' not found.
      final ui.TextHeightBehavior textHeightBehavior;                       
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                           
    ../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/paragraph.dart:78:5: Error: Type 'ui.TextHeightBehavior' not found.
        ui.TextHeightBehavior textHeightBehavior,                           
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                               
    ../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/paragraph.dart:281:3: Error: Type 'ui.TextHeightBehavior' not found.
      ui.TextHeightBehavior get textHeightBehavior => _textPainter.textHeightBehavior;
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                                 
    ../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/paragraph.dart:282:26: Error: Type 'ui.TextHeightBehavior' not found.
      set textHeightBehavior(ui.TextHeightBehavior value) {                 
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                          
    ../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/text_painter.dart:145:5: Error: Type 'ui.TextHeightBehavior' not found.
        ui.TextHeightBehavior textHeightBehavior,                           
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                               
    ../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/text_painter.dart:346:3: Error: Type 'ui.TextHeightBehavior' not found.
      ui.TextHeightBehavior get textHeightBehavior => _textHeightBehavior;  
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                                 
    ../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/text_painter.dart:347:3: Error: Type 'ui.TextHeightBehavior' not found.
      ui.TextHeightBehavior _textHeightBehavior;                            
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                                 
    ../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/text_painter.dart:348:26: Error: Type 'ui.TextHeightBehavior' not found.
      set textHeightBehavior(ui.TextHeightBehavior value) {                 
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                          
    ../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/text_style.dart:1070:5: Error: Type 'ui.TextHeightBehavior' not found.
        ui.TextHeightBehavior textHeightBehavior,                           
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                               
    ../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/basic.dart:5149:12: Error: 'TextHeightBehavior' isn't a type.
      final ui.TextHeightBehavior textHeightBehavior;                       
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                           
    ../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/text.dart:149:12: Error: 'TextHeightBehavior' isn't a type.
      final ui.TextHeightBehavior textHeightBehavior;                       
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                           
    ../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/text.dart:200:43: Error: 'TextHeightBehavior' isn't a type.
        properties.add(DiagnosticsProperty<ui.TextHeightBehavior>('textHeightBehavior', textHeightBehavior, defaultValue: null));
                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^            
    ../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/text.dart:432:12: Error: 'TextHeightBehavior' isn't a type.
      final ui.TextHeightBehavior textHeightBehavior;                       
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                           
    ../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/text.dart:487:43: Error: 'TextHeightBehavior' isn't a type.
        properties.add(DiagnosticsProperty<ui.TextHeightBehavior>('textHeightBehavior', textHeightBehavior, defaultValue: null));
                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^            
    ../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/paragraph.dart:78:8: Error: 'TextHeightBehavior' isn't a type.
        ui.TextHeightBehavior textHeightBehavior,                           
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                               
    ../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/paragraph.dart:282:29: Error: 'TextHeightBehavior' isn't a type.
      set textHeightBehavior(ui.TextHeightBehavior value) {                 
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                          
    ../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/text_painter.dart:145:8: Error: 'TextHeightBehavior' isn't a type.
        ui.TextHeightBehavior textHeightBehavior,                           
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                               
    ../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/text_painter.dart:347:6: Error: 'TextHeightBehavior' isn't a type.
      ui.TextHeightBehavior _textHeightBehavior;                            
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                                 
    ../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/text_painter.dart:348:29: Error: 'TextHeightBehavior' isn't a type.
      set textHeightBehavior(ui.TextHeightBehavior value) {                 
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                          
    ../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/text_painter.dart:422:7: Error: No named parameter with the name 'textHeightBehavior'.
          textHeightBehavior: _textHeightBehavior,                          
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                                
    org-dartlang-sdk:///flutter/lib/ui/text.dart:865:3: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
      ParagraphStyle({                                                      
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                                        
    ../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/text_style.dart:1070:8: Error: 'TextHeightBehavior' isn't a type.
        ui.TextHeightBehavior textHeightBehavior,                           
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                               
    ../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/text_style.dart:1091:7: Error: No named parameter with the name 'textHeightBehavior'.
          textHeightBehavior: textHeightBehavior,   

                        
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                                
org-dartlang-sdk:///flutter/lib/ui/text.dart:865:3: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  ParagraphStyle({                                                      
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                                        
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception: Errors during snapshot creation: null
build failed.                                                           
                                                                        
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

> - Where:                                                                 Script
>   '/Users/mac/Downloads/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle'
>   line: 801

```
* What went wrong:                                                      
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildRelease'.            
> Process 'command '/Users/mac/Downloads/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

**this is my flutter doctor: **

> [✓] Flutter (Channel master, v1.14.7-pre.83, on Mac OS X 10.15.2
> 19C57, locale en-ID)
> • Flutter version 1.14.7-pre.83 at /Users/mac/flutter
> • Framework revision e10df3c1a6 (2 days ago), 2020-02-01 11:23:01 +0800
> • Engine revision e625e174c5
> • Dart version 2.8.0 (build 2.8.0-dev.6.0 5ae5aff640)
>
> [✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK
> version 29.0.2)
> • Android SDK at /Users/mac/Library/Android/sdk
> • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
> • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2
> • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
> • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)
> • All Android licenses accepted.
>
> [✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.3.1)
> • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
> • Xcode 11.3.1, Build version 11C504
> • CocoaPods version 1.8.4
>
> [✓] Android Studio (version 3.5)
> • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
> • Flutter plugin version 43.0.1
> • Dart plugin version 191.8593
> • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)
>
> [✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2018.2.2)
> • IntelliJ at /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app
> • Flutter plugin version 29.1.3
> • Dart plugin version 182.4129.13

Previously I success upload my app to Google Playstore. But when I want to update my app, I face this problem. thank you before

Comment: can you please show your code instead of errors !!!

Comment: Please consider revising the code sample you posted in this question. As it currently stands, its formatting and scope make it hard for us to help you; here is a [great resource](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get you started on that. -1, don't take it the wrong way. A down vote is how we indicate a content problem around here; improve your formatting and code sample and I (or someone will) gladly revert it. Good luck with your code!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

change your flutter master
at terminal of your project  write
flutter channel stable

Answer (score 0):

In your app's pubspec.yaml file look for this line: flutter_widget_from_html and use the version ^ 0.5.1 + 3

Ex: `flutter_widget_from_html: ^0.5.1+3`

Then click on pub upgrade and run your app